# Изменение цвета в textarea с помощью JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть сайт, на нем есть textarea, в ней нужно сделать так чтобы к примеру, если пользователь вводит "#" то вся строка стала красным, а не весь текст в textarea. Уже и там и так пробовал, получается только изменить цвет шрифта во всем texarea, а не с определенного символа и к примеру по конец строки. Вот мой код, на чем я остановился...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".txt_send").change(function(){
        var text = $('.txt_send').val();
        $(".txt_send").css("color", "#F00");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 7):

В не можете поменять отдельно взятую линию текста из области textarea.

**Textarea** может содержать только обычный текст. С общей заменой цвета, размера текста, и шрифтов, как в обычном input.

В вашем случае можно использовать что то вроде редактора [WYSIWYG](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) ([CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5-builds/download/) или [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/))

Answer (score 6):

В textarea это сделать невозможно. Вы можете использовать [contenteditable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) для этого:

```js
code.onkeypress = e => {
  if(e.key === '#'){
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const red = document.createElement('span');
    red.style.color = 'red';
    selection.anchorNode.parentNode.insertBefore(red, selection.anchorNode);
    red.appendChild(selection.anchorNode);
  }
}
```

```html
<code id=code contenteditable="true">
Строчка<br/>
Поставь сюда # <br/>
Строчка
</code>
```

Comment: Мне не совсем это нужно, мне нужен как бы самый элементарный текстовый редактор, чтобы потом с него брать текст и отправлять на сервер Это только для красоты в большей степени...

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать эмуляцию textarea, на contenteditable блоке и при редактировании следить за тем , что если попадает символ '#' то вычислять содержание и "номер" строки по координатам символа от начала блока и окрашивать всю строку.

Придется много чего учесть: размер шрифта, возможность редактирования из любого места в тексте, переносы строк и пр.